# NSPredicate created with format and va_list/NSArray failed but string success

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject, objective-c-category

I created categories of NSManagedObject such as **create**, **count** and else. All of them works find except for following

```
@interface NSManagedObject(ManagedObjectExtension) 
+ (id)findWithPredicate:(id)stringOrPredicate, ...;
@end

@implementation NSManagedObject(ManagedObjectUtilities)

+ (id)findWithPredicate:(id)stringOrPredicate, ... {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [self allFetchRequest];
    if (stringOrPredicate) {
        NSPredicate *predicate;
        if ([stringOrPredicate isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            va_list variadicArguments;
            va_start(variadicArguments, stringOrPredicate);
            predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:stringOrPredicate arguments:variadicArguments];
            va_end(variadicArguments);
        } else {
            predicate = (NSPredicate *)stringOrPredicate;
        }
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    }


    NSError *error;
    NSArray *results = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
    }

    if ([results count] == 0) {
        return nil;
    } else if ([results count] == 1) {
        return [results objectAtIndex:0];
    } else {
        return results;
    }
}

@end
```

And these are results

```
NSString *email = [NSString stringWithString:someTextField.text];
NSLog(@"%@", [User findWithPredicate:@"email == "%@", email]);
==> (null)
NSLog(@"%@", [User findWithPredicate:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"email == "%@", email]]);
==> "<User: 0x1d827e10> ..."
```

Basically, this method works only when I send a string instead of formatted string and arguments. If I print the predicate created inside this method, these are results

```
[User findWithPredicate:@"email == "%@", email];
==> email == "%@"
[User findWithPredicate:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"email == "%@", email]];
==> email == "tar.tw45@gmail.com"
```

Do you have any idea what could cause this? Any comment or suggestion are welcome : )

Comment: is this a typo: @"email == "%@"
should it be: @"email == '%@'"

Comment: @kitschmaster Thank you, it's simple as that, remove single quote fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you forgot the quotation marks in the code of your question (as @kitschmaster said in his comment) and that the code actually looks like this:

```
NSString *email = @"tar.tw45@gmail.com";
// Case 1:
NSLog(@"%@", [User findWithPredicate:@"email == '%@'", email]);
// Case 2:
NSLog(@"%@", [User findWithPredicate:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"email == '%@'", email]]);
```

***In case (1)***, your utility method creates the following predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"email == '%@'", email];
```

and this predicate searches for the *verbatim string* `"%@"` because of the quotation marks. If you remove the quotation marks:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [User findWithPredicate:@"email == %@", email]);
```

then it works correctly.

***In case (2),*** your utility method creates the predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"email == 'tar.tw45@gmail.com'"];
```

because it is called with an already formatted query string. This works in this particular case. But it will fail if the query itself contains any quotation marks. For example:

```
[User findWithPredicate:@"name == %@", @"a'b"]
```

works correctly, but

```
[User findWithPredicate:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"name == '%@'", @"a'b"]]
```

crashes. *The usage of `stringWithFormat` should generally be avoided when creating predicates.*

***Summary:*** The first version works correctly if you omit the quotation marks in the format string. The second version should not be used.

Comment: Thank you, remove single quote from format string fix the problem. I'll keep this in mind. : )